# ModelSim Message Viewer Empty

Tags: message, vhdl, viewer, modelsim

I'm currently using Modelsim 10.1 alongside ISE 13.4 and run a very simple test bench. All code is VHDL.

I ran into trouble using VHDL's `assert` statement the other day: Errors and warnings are output to the transcript. However, there are no messages in the message viewer and there are no message indicators inside the wave window. I start my simulations from within ISE, if that matters.

I think I might be missing a switch to turn message logging on or something, but hours of Googling have brought up nothing. Is there any setting that would prevent messages from being logged to the message viewer albeit being printed out to the transcript?

I already found `Simulate->Runtime Options-->Message Severity`. However, everything is unchecked there. Ticking any check boxes yields the expected behavior of not printing out to the transcript, but there is still no sign of any messages in the message viewer.

Thanks for your time,

Robert

**Edit:**

Okay, after yet some more fiddling and twiddling, I finally found it.

One has to set the `msgmode`and `displaymsgmode` options to at least `both` to have nice message indicators. It seems this was done inside my company's default configuration for earlier ModelSim versions.

I hope somebody as clueless as me find this answer helpful :)

Comment: Hi, I intended to do just that, but it wouldn't let me until 8 hours after asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after yet some more fiddling and twiddling, I finally found it.

One has to set the msgmodeand displaymsgmode options to at least both to have nice message indicators. It seems this was done inside my company's default configuration for earlier ModelSim versions.

I hope somebody as clueless as me find this answer helpful :)

Answer (score 5):

Just to be clear how to start the simulation in order to see the messages (red, green and yellow triangles) on top of the Wave window:

```
vsim -msgmode both -displaymsgmode both your_testbench
```

There exist no GUI to set this up. It has to be done either by typing the command (above) in the Transcript window after having compiled the project, or by adding in "Simulation Properties"->"Others"->"Other Vsim Options" the following code: `-msgmode both -displaymsgmode both`.